# Xcode 7.3 crashes when breakpoint set or app crashes

Tags: xcode, debugging, crash, breakpoints

I am having this issue and when I searched it on Stack Overflow I saw that many people have had this before:

First of all, you can find the crash report here: http://pastebin.com/c726EUip

What I've tried so far:

- I set the "Enable Clang Module Debugging" in Build Setting to NO
- I did `pod update`
- Tried to change LLDB to GDB but i think xcode no longer has this option

This is the list of frameworks:

[image: List of Frameworks]

Here are links to questions from people with the same issue:

- [Xcode 4.3-4.4 crashes with breakpoints using LLDB, breakpoints useless with GDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11905378/xcode-4-3-4-4-crashes-with-breakpoints-using-lldb-breakpoints-useless-with-gdb)
- [Xcode 7.3 crashing when debugging with breakpoints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36161040/xcode-7-3-crashing-when-debugging-with-breakpoints)
- [iOS App crashes when setting breakpoint in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13635577/ios-app-crashes-when-setting-breakpoint-in-xcode)

I am totally desperate on this, as I cannot debug my work properly.

Anyone have ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try going through all these steps in the exact same order    https://stackoverflow.com/a/28371711/821053 This solved my debugging problems a couple of times.